# Will the Numbering Be Safe in Multiple Variable Access

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to shift the numbering of rows in my `SELECT` section to the server side.

I am doing the following:

```
SET @a=0;

SELECT @a:=@a+1, id
       /*, other fields*/
FROM tmytable 
WHERE (id >10) AND (id!= 73) /*etc.*/
order by id desc;
```

The code gives me what I want: the rows are properly numbered despite of `WHERE` clause, ordering and other circumstances. However I wonder how to make the statement safer. I assume that the concurrent sessions might address the same database variable simultaneously and the numbering will start from some undefined value of `@a` different from `0 + 1`. I would prefer to exclude transactions and table locking as I need read only access and table locking might slow down the DB performance. Is there a way to declare and insert a variable within the `SELECT` statement?

[image]

Comment: Each session has its own variables, but that doesn't make this a good way of doing anything.

Comment: @underscore_d Shure. That is why I am asking for the way of making it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use variables.  Use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT row_number() over (order by id desc), id
       #, other fields
FROM tmytable 
WHERE (id > 10) AND (id <> 73) #etc.
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "safe".  This is a SQL query and it will be run as a unit, independently of other sessions (under most circumstances).

Comment: Thank you. As far as I understood it is a new function to MySQL.

Comment: @asd-tm . . . "new" is a relative term.  MySQL 8.0 was released over 2 years ago (April 2018).  And the function has been part of the standard for much, much longer than that.